# How to explain to a client that he must generate his SSL certificate using CSR generated on hosting IIS server?

Tags: ssl-certificate, iis-7.5, csr

I have probably quite easy question:

*How to explain to a client that he must generate his SSL certificate  using CSR generated on hosting IIS server?*

Thank you

Comment: He doesn't have to. He can generate the CSR, get is signed, then upload both keys to you.

Answer (score 2):

By writing understandable documentation.

Comment: Best answer ever!